# Extremum of $f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|\;;\quad0<|x|\leq2\\1\;;\quad x=0\end{cases}$

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

> Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|\;;\quad0<|x|\leq2\\1\;;\quad x=0\end{cases}$ then show that $x=0$ has _________________
>
> (a) a local maximum
>
> (b) no local maximum
>
> (c) local minimum
>
> (d) no extremum

My reference says that there "no extremum" at $x=0$.

$|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ so I think we can look for maxima or minima at $x=0$.

What is wrong with local maxima at $x=0$ for the above function ?

Comment: It seems to me that x=0 is a local extremum (a local max), but x=0 is not a global extremum (neither a global max nor a global min).

Comment: ‘$x=0$’ is not a function. How coud it have, or not, an extremum?

Comment: What does 'prove that $x=0$ has no extremum' mean?

Comment: @Bernard well thats true and a valid point. I really do not know why this was solved as above in my reference.

Comment: @Bernard So are u saying that the question itself is entirely wrong, right ?

Comment: Worse: as it is formulated, it is meaningless.  But one can very well say ‘$x=0$ is not an extremum. B.t.w., is it about a *local* or a *global* extremum?

Comment: How are $f(-2)=f(2)=2$ not global maxima?

Comment: @Bernard why $x=0$ is not an extremum ?. Is it because it is not a function right ?

Comment: @Math1000 does that matter as it is not a function in the given domain ?

Comment: ?? What do you mean it is not a function in the given domain? $f$ is defined on $[-2,2]$, and attains its maximum at $-2$ and $2$. That is clear from the definition of the function. Now, $f$ has no global or local minimum, but that is aside from the point.

Comment: $x=0$ is or is not an extremum – that is a correct ellipsis of ‘ the value  $0$ is (or is not) an extremum. What I mean is that you can't say that $x=0$ *has* an extremum.

Comment: @Math1000 not a "continuous function" in the given domain .

Comment: @Math1000: `x = 0` is not a function, it is an assertion (true or false).

Comment: @Bernard I am confused. I can see that the given function, for the whole domain $[-2,2]$ is not a continuous function. But do not understand how it is not a function. How can I say not being a continuous function implies no extremum ?

Comment: Oh, I did not read the entire question. Indeed, $f$ has no local or global extremum at $0$, as in the neighborhood $(-2,2)$ of $0$ we have points at which $f$ takes lesser values e.g. $f(1/2)=1/2$ and points at which $f$ takes greater values e.g. $f(3/2)=3/2$.

Comment: I didn't say $f$ is not a function. I only said that $\color{red}{x=0}$ is not a function – it is an equality.

Comment: @Bernard Pls read I have edited to include the actual question in my reference. It is solved by saying, since $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ it has "no extremum". That is what I am confused about ?, since we usually look for local maxima or minima for points where $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ is not defined, right ?

Comment: You're  right. Maybe there is a context explaining why non-differentiability is enough to show the assertion?

Comment: @Bernard i mean how can you justify, there is "no extremum" at $x=0$ for the given function ?

Comment: @Math1000 how can I mathematically prove that the given function has no extremum value in the given domain ?. Can I say as follows, $f$ is non differentiable at $x=0$, so it is the only possible extremum, but as we can say $x=0$ is not a local minima due to the reasons you hv mentioned ?

Comment: @Math1000 @ Bernard what is wrong with calling $x=0$ a local maxima, the nearby points to $x=0$ are less than $1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I am off to a bad start today. What I said previously is incorrect. $f$ does admit a *local* maximum at $x=0$, because in the neighborhood $(-1/2,1/2)$ of $0$, $f(x)=1>f(y)$ for any $y\in(-1/2,1/2)$, $y\ne x$.

Comment: @Math1000 So the solution in my reference is wrong ?, it has a local maximum at $x=0$ ?

Comment: I suppose so. $f$ clearly has a *local* maximum at $x=0$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you please comment on $x=0$ is a point of local maximum, thus the reference is wrong ?

Comment: I fully agree  with @Math1000: we have a *local* maximum at $x=0$, and an absolute maximum at $x=2$ and $x=-2$.

Comment: @Bernard @ Math1000 Thanks. and you could write this as answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:[2,0)\cup(0,2]$ be defined by $f(x)=|x|$. Then $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $f'(x)=1$ for $x>0$. Therefore $f$ is decreasing on $[-2,0)$ and so attains a maximum value of $2$ at $x=-2$. Similarly, $f$ is increasing on $(0,2]$ and so attains a maximum value of $2$ at $x=2$.

Let $g(x)=1$ for $x=0$ and let $F(x) = f(x)+g(x)$. Then there exists the neighborhood $(-1/2,1/2)$ of $0$ on which $F(x)<F(0)=1$, so $F$ attains a local maximum at $x=0$.

Since $F(x)\leqslant 2$ for all $x\in[-2,2]$, it follows that $F$ attains its global maximum of $2$ at both $x=-2$ and $x=2$.

Comment: I believe this fully answers the question. Please let me know if there are any other concerns.